# Add number before input box text after validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML form

```
more on top ...
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="phone" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Phone</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" >
    </div>
</div>
more on bottom ...
```

Here I am putting the number e.g 1671133639 and if its validate then I am adding **880 before this number**. But it's adding before the input field, not input text. I mean final result should be: 8801671133639

**JS Code I am using:**

```
if (phone.value == "") { 
    alert("Phone number is required"); 
    phone.focus(); 
    return false; 
} else if (!phoneRegex.test(phone.value)) {
    alert("Phone number must contain only numerical value."); 
    phone.focus(); 
    return false; 
} else if ( phone.length > 13 ) {
    alert("Invalid phone number is given."); 
    phone.focus(); 
    return false; 
} else {
    var text    = document.createTextNode('+88');
    var child   = document.getElementById('phone');
    child.parentNode.insertBefore(text, child);
}
```

Comment: You should modify the value of input not create a new node. Get value of input using .value property and add your number and set it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `insertBefore`, assign the new string to the input's `value` attribute.

```
const text    = '+88';
const child   = document.getElementById('phone');
const value = child.value;
phone.value = text + value;
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const text = "+88";
    const phoneInput = document.getElementById('phone');
    const value = phoneInput.value;
    phoneInput.value = text + value;
})
```

```html
<input type="text" value="1671133639" type="string" id="phone">
<button>Append Phone Code</button>
```

Comment: If I type 2 then its added this text- [object Text]2

Comment: The const text should not be documented.createTextNode, right?

Comment: @creativeartbd - See edit, don't create use `createTextNode`.